# SQL Server 2000 DTS Invalid pointer

Tags: sql-server-2000, dts

Morning folks,

I have this annoying error every time I execute the query on my DTS step. It returns "Invalid Pointer" while the query executes successfully on the Query Analyser.

I tried the :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

==> No success. Even more with the SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF I get a new error..

Does anyone have an idea about this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the problem was from another query and the SET NOCOUNT ON did make it work in the end.